# Application logs are not getting logged using log4j2

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, log4j2, jboss-eap-7

I am using Spring Boot and Apache Camel in my application and deploying in JBoss EAP 7.3.0 as war files. Previously the startup logs and logs from the application were getting logged to the log file when I was using log4j 1.x and the below log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, out, FILE

log4j.appender.out=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.out.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=fileName.log
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=200MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Now I have shifted to log4j 2.17.1 and using the below lg4j2.properties:

```
rootLogger.level = INFO
property.filename = fileName.log
appenders = FILE, console

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

appender.FILE.type = RollingFile
appender.FILE.name = File
appender.FILE.fileName = ${filename}
appender.FILE.filePattern = ${filename}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.FILE.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.FILE.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
appender.FILE.policies.type = Policies
appender.FILE.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.FILE.policies.time.interval = 1

rootLogger.appenderRefs = FILE, console

rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.FILE.ref = File
```

But now only the below logs are coming during application startup and no logs are gettig logged from the application:

2022-08-13 00:52:12 ContextLoader [INFO] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2022-08-13 00:52:31 ContextLoader [INFO] Root WebApplicationContext initialized in 19250 ms

Can anyone please suggest what am I doing wrong?

To add, I can see the logs from Spring Boot ApplicationContext during startup, but not the logs which are logged by the application. This is kind of strange.

Comment: Your log file name may be incorrect.

Comment: No it is not, the log file is getting generated with minimal logs during startup

Comment: What logging facade/framework do you use in your application? Do you still use log4j 1.x loggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also I don't know how exactly you have it configured and packaged, but you may need to exclude the logging subsystem via jboss-deployment-structure.xml (located in war/WEB-INF or ear/META-INF):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.3">
  <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
      <!-- disable the logging subsystem because the application manages its own logging independently -->
      <subsystem name="logging" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

In the case of ear you'll also need to handle exclusions for any included modules via the sub-deployment elements, or try to use ear-exclusions-cascaded-to-subdeployments (available since jboss-deployment-structure:1.3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.3">
  <ear-exclusions-cascaded-to-subdeployments>true</ear-exclusions-cascaded-to-subdeployments>
  <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
      <!-- disable the logging subsystem because the application manages its own logging independently -->
      <subsystem name="logging" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this and post whether this has worked.

Comment: excluding the logging subsystem of jboss worked, thanks Petr

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using all the dependencies.

org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-api
org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-core

And for a logging into a file u can go ahead refer below link. It shows log4j2.properties file.
https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/log4j2-properties-example/

I hope this helps

Comment: Had tried this and it did not work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).